# HP Tilt pen support in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, hp, digitalpen

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in the [HP Spectre x360](https://store.hp.com/SwitzerlandStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=4UJ75EA&opt=UUZ&sel=NTB). Everything works well, except the [HP tilt pen](https://store.hp.com/SwitzerlandStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=2MY21AA&opt=ABB&sel=ACC&lang=en-CH&gclid=Cj0KCQiAzePjBRCRARIsAGkrSm4jgjPc5v9Bk8gl8Z4YfbI8pjrWaSyvJwOlAnHJr3apU7FnI5-hV_4aAq4uEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). It does get connected via Bluetooth but gets recognized as a wireless keyboard. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Also, please let me know if there are any other ways by which I can use pen support. Or does connecting to Wacom table work? Any ideas are welcomed since I wish to stick to Ubuntu on this laptop.

Comment: did you ever do an `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` because most of the functionality should [work out of the box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105108/functionality-hp-tilt-pen-on-spectre-x360-13-ae002ns) with newer kernel versions.

Comment: @Fabby Thanks! It started working now following your comment!! I can give you the bounty if you post this comment in the answer section!!

Comment: Bounty gone, but...  **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HP Tilt Pen works [out of the box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105108/functionality-hp-tilt-pen-on-spectre-x360-13-ae002ns) on fully updated version of 18.04 and above, so simply do a:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

and it'll just work!